# How to send some data to downstream when executing cancel with Flink

Tags: apache-flink

The 'AbstractUdfStreamOperator' class and 'OneInputStreamOperator' interface of Flink. How to proactively send some data to downstream during 'cancel'? If sent in the close method, downstream will not receive it, while in the 'finish method', it will only be called at the end of the process, and 'cancel' will not call this method

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichFlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.Utils;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor;
import org.apache.flink.metrics.groups.OperatorMetricGroup;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OneInputStreamOperator;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.Output;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamrecord.StreamRecord;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * @author LaiYongBIn
 * @date 2023/7/5 10:09
 * @Description Do SomeThing
 */
public class Test {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        DataStream<String> stream0 =
                env.addSource(new SourceFunction<String>() {
                            private SourceContext<String> sourceContext;

                            @Override
                            public void run(SourceContext<String> sourceContext) throws Exception {
                                this.sourceContext = sourceContext;
                                for (;;) {
                                    sourceContext.collect("TEST");
                                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void cancel() {
                                this.sourceContext.collect("source stream cancel message");
                                LOG.info("--------------------run finish--------------------");
                            }
                        })
                        .setParallelism(1);
        MyFlatMapFun flatMapFunc = new MyFlatMapFun();
        TypeInformation<String> outType = TypeExtractor.getFlatMapReturnTypes(env.clean(flatMapFunc), stream0.getType(), Utils.getCallLocationName(), true);

        DataStream<String> flatMap = stream0.transform("Flat Map", outType, new MyStreamOperator(env.clean(flatMapFunc), env)).setParallelism(1);

        flatMap.flatMap(new RichFlatMapFunction<String, String>() {


            @Override
            public void flatMap(String s, Collector<String> collector) throws Exception {
                LOG.info("Obtain upstream data is：" + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws Exception {
                LOG.info("flatMap close method");
            }


        });

        env.execute();
    }
}


class MyStreamOperator extends AbstractUdfStreamOperator<String, FlatMapFunction<String, String>> implements OneInputStreamOperator<String, String> {


    private transient TimestampedCollector<String> collector;

    public MyStreamOperator(FlatMapFunction<String, String> userFunction, StreamExecutionEnvironment env) {
        super(userFunction);
    }

    @Override
    public void open() throws Exception {
        collector = new TimestampedCollector<>(output);
    }


    @Override
    protected Output<StreamRecord<String>> registerCounterOnOutput(Output<StreamRecord<String>> output, OperatorMetricGroup operatorMetricGroup) {
        return super.registerCounterOnOutput(output, operatorMetricGroup);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
         System.out.println("close function");
         collector.collect("close message");
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() throws Exception {
        collector.collect("finish message");
        LOG.info("finish function");
    }



    @Override
    public void processElement(StreamRecord<String> streamRecord) throws Exception {
        collector.collect(streamRecord.getValue());
    }
}


class MyFlatMapFun implements FlatMapFunction<String, String> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyFlatMapFun.class);
    @Override
    public void flatMap(String s, Collector<String> collector) throws Exception {
         LOG.info("get message：" + s);
    }
}
```

I want to send a piece of data downstream when the user calls to cancel the task, wait for its calculation to be completed before ending the process